# Error in expo: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am facing a problem in expo that it is showing:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.
```

This error is located at:
in RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig (created by HeaderConfig)
in HeaderConfig (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen
in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import LogoPage from './Pages/LogoPage';
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import Sale from './Pages/Sale';
import Purchase from './Pages/Purchase';
import Addparty from './Pages/Addparty';
import AddProduct from './Pages/AddProduct';
import VoucherReport from './Pages/VoucherReport';
import CreateVoucher from './Pages/CreateVoucher';
import CashBook from './Pages/CashBook';
import LedgerReport from './Pages/LedgerReport';
import AllParty from './Pages/AllParty';
import Scrollpage from './Pages/Scrollpage';
import AllProduct from './Pages/AllProduct';
import SaleReport from './Pages/SaleReport';
import PurchaseReport from './Pages/PurchaseReport';
import FirstLogin from './Pages/FirstLogin';
import Profile from './Pages/Profile';
import { UserActivityProvider } from './Pages/UserActivityProvider'; // Adjust the 
import path

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="LogoPage"
          component={LogoPage}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="FirstLogin"
          component={FirstLogin}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Scrollpage"
          component={Scrollpage}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
        />

    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="Add Party"
      component={Addparty}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="Add Product"
      component={AddProduct}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="Sale"
      component={Sale}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="Purchase"
      component={Purchase}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="VoucherReport"
      component={VoucherReport}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="CreateVoucher"
      component={CreateVoucher}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="CashBook"
      component={CashBook}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="LedgerReport"
      component={LedgerReport}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="All Party"
      component={AllParty}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="All Product"
      component={AllProduct}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="Sale Report"
      component={SaleReport}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="Purchase Report"
      component={PurchaseReport}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="Profile"
      component={Profile}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      //  options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name="UserActivityProvider"
      component={UserActivityProvider}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

);
};

export default App;